# PHP is_file returns false (incorrectly) for Windows share on Ubuntu

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, samba

Ubuntu server, PHP 5.3, connected via Samba to Windows server share.

I am using file_exists() to check for availability of file on Windows machine. It returns false, although the filepath does exist. Meanwhile, file_get_contents() on the exact same filepath works fine.

I'm wondering if it's a permission issue, since I'm having trouble configuring permissions of the files on the Windows share (it says I don't have permission to change permissions on them). When I look at the permissions through Nautilus, it says the user and group are both root, with 755 rights. I'd like to change the group to www-data, but can't seem to do it.

Comment: Are you using an absolute or a relative path? I've had some strange problems with PHP relative path's on Windows. Not that this helps....

Comment: Can you give the path of the file (as you are checking)? As celalo mentionned, it may be the directory seperator - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: The path: /media/k/Jobs-Microtech2/CDRemote.sta

/media/k is a directory holding a Windows share (via Samba).

Also, remember that I can open the file with file_get_contents() so there can't be anything too wrong with the directory separators.

One note: I found a PHP bug from last November that indicates there was a problem with junctions / symlinks. Apparently they've fixed it, but I'm not sure it has made it out yet.

I have figured out a workaround:

$size = exec ('stat -c %s '. escapeshellarg ($filepath));

It returns "" for a non-existent file, or an integer for an existing file.

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles across this question, as I did today: There is [PHP-Bug #62199](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62199), which seems to "care" (or not) about this issue. Also compare [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818770/php-is-readable-fails-on-readable-samba-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It could be directory seperators. Try `preg_replace('%(\\|\)%', '/', $path)`

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't it. I've actually simplified to try to catch the problem. I created a string with a known working filepath. I'm thinking it has to do with permissions or some sort of symlink.