# PHP is_readable returns true for non-readable file

Tags: php, file-permissions, getimagesize

I have an image processor PHP script, and it contains the following code:

```
        if (!is_dir($fullFile)) {
            if (is_readable($fullFile)) {
                $im = getimagesize($fullFile); // Will be FALSE if not an image
```

In some instances, the script will fail at getimagesize with the following error:

```
getimagesize(/path/to/file.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: Permission denied at www.yada.yada/page.php
```

In this case, the permissions for /path/to/file.jpg are definitely prohibitive (400), so I'd have expected the is_readable test to prevent me getting to that point.  Aside from setting permissions differently, what might I do in order to resolve this?  Why does it seem that is_readable has an incorrect result?  Is it possible that is_readable is operating with the EUID of the file owner, while getimagesize is not?  That's the only explanation that makes sense to me, but even that knowledge doesn't help resolve.

Prompted by @hek2mgl I created this ultra-complex script, named readable.php:

```
<?php echo is_readable("/stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG") . "\n\n"; ?>
```

Then I switched user to the web server user (actually www-data on this server) and ran it.  Result was

```
1
```

Then I ran strace as that same user.  These are the commands I used.  The result is a 70KB+ file, and SO won't let me post it in its entirety, so it is posted at http://pastebin.com/mFqiSBiz

```
dennis@luke:~$ sudo su - www-data

$ ls -l "/stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG"
-rw------- 1 dennis dennis 524288 2012-02-11 08:18 /stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG

$ file "/stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG"
/stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG: writable, regular file, no read permission

$ php /home/dennis/readable.php
1

$ strace php /home/dennis/readable.php > /tmp/strace.out 2>&1
```

Not sure what I'm looking for.  Please advise.

Comment: *"Keep in mind that PHP may be accessing the file as the user id that the web server runs as (often 'nobody')."*

Comment: The result could also be cached. Try [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: What user owns the file and what user is your web server running as?

Comment: could you run this code, `var_dump($fullFile, is_dir($fullFile), is_readable($fullFile));` ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - result is string(41) "/stora2/Pics/2009/2009-07-26/DSC00532.JPG"
bool(false)
bool(true)

Comment: @MikeBrant - the webserver is running as apache; the owner of the file is dennis.  The file is actually on an SMB share.  I expected is_readable to fail.

Comment: @Phil - thanks I didn't realize this could be cached.  I added the code right before is_readable, and no joy - the result did not change.

Comment: Are you familar with strace? :)

Comment: A [bugreport](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62199) has already been filed on a problem that might be related to this.

Comment: Apache and CIFS = a world of pain

Comment: @hek2mgl I have run strace, but not for a web page or, more accurately, to trace a web server's activities.  Initial quick searches don't reveal a way to do this, and the script would be a bear to run from command line.

Comment: Isn't it possible to reproduce the problem with a simple cli script? Would suggest

Comment: @hek2mgl D'oh!  Yes I can reproduce.  I had my head where it absolutely doesn't belong, there for a minute.  Bug report: GREAT FIND!  Thanks!

Comment: There is also a [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818770/php-is-readable-fails-on-readable-samba-directory) on this. (Questioner is the opener of the bug report) ... Would be nice to hear a solution on this if you can find one.. Good Luck!

Comment: @hek2mgl I ran strace, but cannot share the full result.  I've updated the question with the tease from that.  Sorry it's only a tease; I am uncertain what parts of the output are essential, and SO limits my posts to 30,000 bytes.  Can't blame 'em.

Comment: you can post it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link. (Great update to question!) really awsome bug!

Comment: Done, thanks.  Link posted in question and here.  http://pastebin.com/mFqiSBiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what version of php you are running, this could be a bug, as hek2mgl said in the comments. If you want to workaround this, you can add logic based on the file permissions, with [fileperms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

Comment: Got me past the hump, thanks.  I used: >>> if (fileperms(&fullFile) & 0x04 == 0x04) {  <<< in place of >>> if (is_readable(&fullFile)) { <<<