# is_file always returns false

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

### The Problem

I'm having an issue with the PHP function `is_file()`.

Some preliminaries: I'm developing on Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bit, using PHP 5.5.10 and Apache 2.4.9.

I'm currently rewriting some working code to convert it to a library in Laravel (completed with a Facade and a ServiceProvider). I'm doing this mainly to clean up some code I wrote when I was young and foolish (about 6 months ago) and to implement unit testing. The library I'm writing provides methods for taking a contract (of which there are two distinct types, with more to come) and finding the path to a PDF document (the scanned paper contract). My methods for finding the path work fine and the tests are all passing.

In my old code, I used to do this:

```
/**
 * Get a scanned contract and return it to the client
 *
 * @param string $type
 * The contract type. Must be either static::CONTRACT1 or static::CONTRACT2.
 * 
 * @param string $contract_id
 * The contract ID
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public static function get($type, $contract_id)
{
    // get the file name
    //
    $results = static::getFileName($type, $contract_id);

    // did we find a file? if not, throw a ScannedContractNotFoundException
    //
    if(!$results)
        throw new \MyApplication\Exceptions\ScannedContractNotFoundException("No file found for $type contract $contract_id");

    // get the path and file name
    //
    $path = $results['path'];
    $name = $results['name'];

    // get the full path
    //
    $file = $path.$name;

    // get the file size
    //
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $fsize = strlen($contents);

    // push the file to the client
    //
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$name."\"");
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");

    echo $contents;

    exit;
}
```

And it worked just fine.

Now I'm trying to rewrite it to get rid of the `echo` and move the code that actually does the work of sending the file to a controller. That code will look like this:

```
$x = \MyApplication\Models\Contract1::find($id);

$file = \ScannedContracts::getFileName($x);

$path = $file["path"].$file["name"];

return \Response::download($path, $file["name"]);
```

However, this code is throwing a `FileNotFoundException`. The code where the exception is being thrown looks like this:

```
public function __construct($path, $checkPath = true)
{
    if ($checkPath && !is_file($path)) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
    }

...
```

Clearly the problem is with the `if` statement, and in particular the call to `is_file()`.

I have written a little script to test this with a path which is known to be good and `is_file()` returns false.

When I copy a file to my "public" folder, it works fine.

In [the documentation for the `is_file()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) there is a comment stating that the permissions for the parent folder must be `+x`. I've examined the permissions, and the folder is world-executable, as is the parent, and the grand-parent, and the great-grand-parent, etc.

There are two possible confounding factors: first, the files I'm working with are located on a CIFS/Samba share. I should mention that the paths in question are absolute paths to the mounted share.

The closest issue to this I've found on SO is [PHP is_file returns false (incorrectly) for Windows share on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504926/php-is-file-returns-false-incorrectly-for-windows-share-on-ubuntu), but that doesn't have a resolution. I've also searched for PHP bug reports, but there's nothing.

Second, some of the paths contain spaces. I've tried escaping them every way I can think of, but it doesn't help.

In the absence of a solution, I'll have to do it the old fashioned way, but I really wanted to do it using the functions Laravel provides.

### Questions

1. Do I need to escape spaces in a path passed to `is_file()`?
2. Does anyone know of a fix or a workaround that doesn't a) require changing code in a 3rd party library, or b) require wholesale changes to permissions or other configuration on the CIFS/Samba server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. -> yes - you cannot use spaces, replace spaces with `%20` -> other than that it should work as expected -> the only thing is if a file is anything other than a 'Regular file' it won't work - but I cannot see you trying to access 'Special Files' in this way anyway :-P

Comment: Did you try in a cli to do `php -r 'var_dump(is_file("/path/to/your/win/share"));'` ? And by the way, Does apache has read access on this folder ? no open_base_dir restriction ? no safe_mode ?

Comment: @naab it's a web application and, in answer to all your other questions about environment, I _am_ able to download the exact same file from the share using the old code. I did test `is_file("/path/to/my/win/share/file.pdf")` and it returned false.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie "yes - you cannot use spaces" -  `php -r 'var_dump(is_file("/tmp/toto a/a"));'` prints : bool(true)  (and the file exists)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I tried replacing spaces in the path with both `%20` and `%020` - neither worked.

Comment: @Kryten seems to be a bug in PHP : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62199 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49620 . I wouldn't be surprised if `is_file()` is buggy too.

Comment: @naab yeah, I saw those bugs too, but wasn't sure if they were relevant. Reading through some of the links, I see someone else commented that "`is_readable()` just wraps the access system call to determine the file permission, so it´s very likely not a php issue" (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818770/php-is-readable-fails-on-readable-samba-directory). This looks like it goes much deeper than just PHP :-P Thanks for all your help, @naab & @GrahamRitche

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to sanitize filenames when upload to directory

```
function sanitize_file_name( $str ) {
    return preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", "", strtolower($str));
}
```